# Difference between "mündig", "volljährig", and "reif"

Tags: meaning, difference, german-to-english

I have been looking at various sources to try to figure out the difference between "mündig", "volljährig", and "reif".

I understand that "reif" means mature, but also that "mündig" can also be translated as mature, as well as "of age", which is what "volljährig" seems to be. I've also seen sentences such as "sich mündig verhalten", but not "sich volljährig verhalten".

Answer (score 7):

**Mündig** means one had no **Vormund**, no legal guardian. In the not-so-far- away past, people could be *entmündigt* in Germany if certain conditions were met (age-related insanity for example). Now people are *betreut* in this case, so the word *mündig* came out of use.

**Reif** is usually combined with *geistig* or *körperlich* and means *adult-like*.

**Volljährig** means "18 years old" in Germany, Austria, Switzerland. It was different (21, 19, 20 years) before.

See [the whole table](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Altersstufen_im_deutschen_Recht) if you want to bemuse yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Very confusing indeed! So, in terms of translating these terms, would "sich mündig verhalten" be, "behave responsibly/like an adult", and "sich reif verhalten" be "behave maturely/not like a child"?

Comment: *Sich mündig verhalten* is a really odd phrase, same as *mündiger Bürger* etc. There's no deeper logic in that, they all use *mündig* for being the contrary of *unmündig* which means you have a legal custodian. The meaning almost always is *don't treat us as four-year-olds* and *then don't act as four-year-olds*.

Comment: *Reif* is also a minefield. *Sich reif verhalten* means thinking about risks before taking it, but e.g. *sich reif geben* means faking it, to the extend of faking your age for getting access to clubs, drugs and more.

Comment: Haha! German is so difficult :) How would you translate: He needs to act more mature. (Stop acting like a kid, act like an adult).

Comment: I would translate this as "Er sollte sich erwachsener verhalten/benehmen" (erwachsen=grown up as an adjective)

Comment: ... *at least* 18 years old. I'd say a *mündiger Bürger* etc. is a person who is able to make valid decisions for himself, so he doesn't need a *Vormund* to make decisions for him, that is, he doesn't need to be *bevormundet*.

Answer (score 1):

You can say "sich reif verhalten" I would say it can be used as a synonym for "erwachsen". Both words can be used as adverbs. Mündig und volljährig are normally not used as adverbs and these terms normally come up in formal language, not in every day language.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is sufficiently different to the ones given, so I provide an own answer.

The words are different enough, so that they are exchangeable only in very rare cases:

- **volljährig** of age, old enough to marry, to smoke, to drink liquor and sign contracts. This is a term with strong legal connotation. Therefore you can't behave *volljährig*, either you are or you are not.
- **mündig** May mean *of age* too, but the second Duden definition is more generic and appropriate in my opinion: as an adult being able to form judgements and decisions of ones own. (Surely it is not too difficult to imagine adults, which will never qualify for this meaning.)
- **reif** I would not recommend to use it for humans at all except in phrases like *reif für sein Alter*, *frühreif* and with similar additional explanation. It is frequently used as marketing term for the senior generation.
- **erwachsen** (corresponding to *adult*), the most generic term, in case of doubt use this.